# Unable to use SPE with Azure AD login

Tags: powershell-extensions, azure-ad

When I login into the Sitecore CMS using Azure AD, and open SPE, It prompts for the password.
I tried entering the Azure AD password but it is not accepted.

I have also enabled this `\App_Config\Include\Spe\Spe.IdentityServer.config`, but no luck.

Checked this [article](https://github.com/SitecorePowerShell/Console/issues/1196), but could not figure out what needs to be done for the fix.

This is Sitecore 10.1.3 on Managed Cloud.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the official documentation you will need to change the Elevation Action from `Password` to `Confirm`.

https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/security